# Subtracting two columns within the sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to subtract two columns in sql server to form a third one.  Below is my query

```
select  AD.Id, Sum(APS.Amount) AS TotalDue,
isnull((select sum(Amount) from Activation where InvoiceId in (select InvoiceId from Invoices where AgreementId = AD.Id)),0)
As AllocatedToDate 
from AdvantageDetails AD 
inner join AllPaymentsSubstantial APS
on APS.AgreementId=AD.Id
where AD.OrganizationId=30
group by AD.Id
```

What I tried is below but it is not working. :

```
select  AD.Id, Sum(APS.Amount) AS TotalDue,
isnull((select sum(Amount) from Activation where InvoiceId in (select InvoiceId from Invoices where AgreementId = AD.Id)),0)
As AllocatedToDate , (TotalDue-AllocatedToDate) as NewColumn
from AdvantageDetails AD 
inner join AllPaymentsSubstantial APS
on APS.AgreementId=AD.Id
where AD.OrganizationId=30
group by AD.Id
```

At last I tried it using a CTE which worked fine. But I want to do it without creating CTE. Can there be any other way for performing the same functionality. I do not want to use CTE because it is forcasted that there
can be other columns which will be calculated in future.

```
with CTE as(select  AD.Id, Sum(APS.Amount) AS TotalDue,
isnull((select sum(Amount) from Activation where InvoiceId in (select InvoiceId from Invoices where AgreementId = AD.Id)),0)
As AllocatedToDate , (TotalDue-AllocatedToDate) as NewColumn
from AdvantageDetails AD 
inner join AllPaymentsSubstantial APS
on APS.AgreementId=AD.Id
where AD.OrganizationId=30
group by AD.Id) select * , (CTE.TotalDue-CTE.AllocatedToDate)As Newcolumn from CTE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without a CTE by repeating the entire formula that makes up AllocatedToDate.

You cannot use the alias of a column in the SELECT list, so you cannot do this:

```
SELECT {some calculation} AS ColumnA, (ColumnA - ColumnB) AS ColumnC
```

If you don't want to use a CTE or derived table, you have to do this:

```
SELECT {some calculation} AS ColumnA, ({some calculation} - ColumnB) AS ColumnC
```

And by the way, I can't imagine why the possibility of future columns being added is a reason not to use a CTE.   To me, it sounds like a reason TO use a CTE, as you will only have to make changes in one place in the code, and not duplicate the same code in different places in the same query.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use nested queries:

```
select Id, TotalDue, AllocatedToDate, (TotalDue-AllocatedToDate) as NewColumn
from (
    select  AD.Id, Sum(APS.Amount) AS TotalDue,
        isnull((select sum(Amount) from Activation where InvoiceId in (select InvoiceId from Invoices where AgreementId = AD.Id)),0)
        As AllocatedToDate 
    from AdvantageDetails AD 
    inner join AllPaymentsSubstantial APS
        on APS.AgreementId=AD.Id
    where AD.OrganizationId=30
    group by AD.Id
) x
```